# GitHub Codespaces Terminal uses the wrong keyboard layout

Tags: github, codespaces

Is started a GitHub codespace for https://github.com/shopware/development and have a German keyboard, which works fine on my Ubuntu 20.04.

When editing code in the code space, all works fine.

But when I try to type `curl localhost:80` in the built-in terminal, it types a ">" instead of ":", so I believe the English keymap is in place.

[image: wrong keymap in terminal]

Changing the keyboard layout via Ctrl+Shift+P "Change keyboard layout" has no effect, it does not even select "de"

[image: change keyboard layout]

Is this a common issue? How can this be fixed? Shall I report an issue to GitHub (where?)

Comment: FYI I created a feature request to improve this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135960

Comment: Commenting because I found that switching to "es" generally works, from there you can also switch to "de"

Comment: wow that is interesting